# What is the best way to have multiple web servers feed to 1 website?

Tags: linux, windows, hosting, sharing

I've got a Linux web server that responds to http requests from the web through a simple port-forward. The domain name points to my IP and the requests are forwarded to apache. Apache checks the domain name and serves the correct website.

Now I want to include another webpage, but this can only be served from a Windows machine. I don't have expensive equipment that can do different forwards based on the URL that is requested, so I was thinking to maybe use an html page with an IFRAME, pulling the data from Windows through my Linux box.
Not sure if this is the preferred way to do this. (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224648/include-a-website-in-php-file)

There is no heavy load on the servers and the code on both servers is completely under my control, so I have no worries about code security.

I'm just thinking now that maybe there's a better way to tackle this problem, I just don't know what's bests practise.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the iframe option and just look at a straight forward proxying solution.   If your Linux box is running apache as you say you can setp the virtualhost in apache (if using another domain) or a directory/location directive if it's just for a suburl and you can use [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) to proxy it to the windows system such as,

```
<Location /windows>
ProxyPass http://192.168.1.1
</Location>
```

Where 192.168.1.1 is the IP of the windows server (you can specify ports, etc too)

Comment: So far I haven't had much luck with this, getting a 500 error trying to proxy through apache and I don't really understand why... error logs not making much sense to me. 
"No protocol handler was valid for the URL /support/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule."

Comment: In /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/, I've got proxy.conf, proxy.load and proxy_uwsgi.load

Comment: Can you show me your proxy pass line.  Are you maybe forwarding to https without mod_ssl , either that or the proxy module isn't actually loaded (httpd -M)